# How do I install Node.js modules on machines without an Internet connection?

Tags: node.js, caching, module, offline

I need to install a Node.js application in a strictly controlled production environment that does not allow an Internet connection.

Is this possible, for instance by populating a Node.js module cache somewhere?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS module installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667418/nodejs-module-installation)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I went with in the end was to run `npm install` and then zip up the entire Node.js application folder.

Answer (score 0):

In node.js 1.0 there was an option added to npm to decide whether to install modules globally or locally. [Go have a look here](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation) it should probably solve your problem...

Comment: Global vs local installation doesn't solve the issue of not having Internet access.

Comment: What I mean is install the modules locally and then distribute the whole program with the modules already installed. At least that's what I do, I have a reference device (raspberry pi) where I compile my node.js package + update my program&libs, I then distribute both to my devices that aren't internet enabled (they don't have direct internet access, just network access)

Comment: Ah right :) The mentioned [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9667520/893780) has a nice solution too for this situation.